# Encontrar latitude e longitude através do cep com python

Tags: python, cep

Estou tentando executar um código que encontrei numa resposta aqui mesmo, com a intenção de retornar a latitude e longitude fazendo a busca pela lista de ceps que tenho

O arquivo contém 1078 ceps diferentes

Estou utilizando o google colab para executar esse código

começo instalando a biblioteca
`pip install pycep-correios`

depois executo esse bloco de código

```
lista_ceps = []   
with open('ceps_rc.csv') as file:
    next(file)  # Pula o cabeçalho, caso exista
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        lista_ceps.append(row[0])
```

após isso, executo esse

```
import pycep_correios
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

def extrai_lat_long(cep):
    endereco = pycep_correios.get_address_from_cep(cep)

    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test_app")
    location = geolocator.geocode(endereco['logradouro'] + ", " + endereco['cidade'] + " - " + endereco['bairro'])

    return(location.latitude, location.longitude)
```

e num terceiro momento

```
with open('ceps_lat_long.csv', 'w') as file:
     cabecalho = ['cep', 'latitude', 'longitude']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=cabecalho)

     writer.writeheader() # Escreve o cabeçalho
     for cep in lista_ceps:
         latitude, longitude = extrai_lat_long(cep)
         writer.writerow({'cep': cep, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude})
```

estou tendo problema nessa linha
`latitude, longitude = extrai_lat_long(cep)`

ao executar essa sequencia, sem que ocorra o erro na linha acima, me é retornado um arquivo em .csv somente com a descrição "cep, latitude, longitude" substituindo a tabela com os ceps

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O geolocator pode retornar um None caso não encontre o endereço, gerando um erro quando retorna a location. Um if já resolverá.

```python
def extrai_lat_long(cep):
    endereco = pycep_correios.get_address_from_cep(cep)
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test_app")
    location = geolocator.geocode(endereco['logradouro'] + ", " + 
    endereco['cidade'] + " - " + endereco['bairro'])
    if location:
        return location.latitude, location.longitude
    return 'latitude não encontrada', 'longitude não encontrada'
```